# automate mongo db backup through amazon web service

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

how can we automate mongo db backup through AWS portal, we have standalone mongo db setup, we are logging through EC2 instance...and then logging through  mongo pod, no replica set  configured , we are able to take db backup using mongodump, but we want to automate the job through portal, how can we do it, any steps.

Comment: can we use S3 to create automation in AWS for mongodump backup.

Answer (score 0):

Make an sh which back up database

```
mongodump -h $SERVER_NAME:$PORT -d "XXX" -u $DATABASE_USER -p $PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase XXX --out /home/ubuntu/backUp/
```

Then use it on crontab:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/ubuntu/backUp/backUp.sh
```

This crontab runs every day at 00:00

You can change output folder, using e.g. aws s3 bucket

Comment: Thanks Luis, can we automate the process directly with aws portal, can we take mongodb backup  completely using AWS tools -. 
AWS provides backup via AWS backup, not just using a script to take a backup and store it on s3.